# Why does not full mean full?

Tags: camera, storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Razer Phone running 8.1.0.
When I go to the camera app, it says Device Storage Full
[image: Device Storage Full]
But my device is not full. I have 2.34 GB free (of 64GB) in system memory (I do not have an SD card installed). Shouldn't that be enough to take a few hundred pictures?

Comment: Use an app like [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) to actually see what is taking up place and free up space by deleting unnecessary files. If that doesn't help, post a screen shot in your question

Comment: @beeshyams I did post a screenshot. And I already have space for pictures. 2 GB free. That's in the question. An I missing something?

Comment: @beeshyams alternatively, I could say you're begging the question. How much do I need to delete to take pictures?

Comment: The answer can be found in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Main point: depends on *where* those 2.34G are free. Doesn't help if it's on the SD card. As the error messages writes: **Device Storage** full. That's the internal storage.

Comment: @Izzy I do not have an SD card. I have 2 gb free in system memory.

Comment: @Izzy The insufficient memory tag wiki states that a low space alarm is triggered at 10%. Does that mean I can't take pictures unless I have 6.4gb free?

Comment: Try clearing cache maybe it'll help

Comment: @McKay that might indeed be the case – though the ROM dev might have defined a different limit. 6G would be ridiculous, but if the devs forgot, that's the default.

Comment: @izzy, well, that theory fails, because I freed to 6.0 gb, (which is 9%), and I could take pictures again.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје, that didn't work.

Comment: @McKay then the "ROM baker" might have set it to 5% – your 2G would be below that (3%) while your 6G is beyond (9%).